# Is there any advantage of using XMLHttpRequest over $.ajax (JQuery)?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I understand that $.ajax is utilizing XMLHttpRequest to accomplish the same task and that there is a slight difference in terms of speed,I also realize that XHR can be tailor-made to meet my requirements but my doubt is with respect to functionality.

Basically I would like to know if $.ajax can accomplish everything that XHR can or is XHR superrior somehow.

If there isn't any advantage of XHR over $.ajax, should I try and understand all the Http header requests or just be satisfied with $.ajax?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things `$.ajax` doesn't have built-in functionality for (like aborting a request) but `$.ajax` actually returns the XMLHttpRequest object, which allows you to [tap into and manipulate that directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery).

Since jQuery just extends XMLHttpRequest there's nothing that I can think of that XMLHttpRequest can do that you can't accomplish with the jQuery extension as well.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of `XMLHttpRequest` is that it doesn't require jQuery.

If you're already using jQuery, then `$.ajax` is probably your best option - it'll give you some simplicity that `XMLHttpRequest` doesn't offer, without any real significant overhead.

Comment: yes but adding jQuery just for the sake of simplicity doesn't seem like overkill.. what I mean to say is why not just stick with $.ajax

Comment: @Sahal and I'm saying that you *should* just stick with `$.ajax`. "Adding jQuery for the sake of simplicity" makes sense for a lot of things. There are corner cases where it doesn't (e.g. bookmarklets).